# How do I invert BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, visibility

I'm using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` in WPF to bind the `Visibility` property of a control to a `Boolean`. This works fine, but I'd like one of the controls to hide if the boolean is `true`, and show if it's `false`.

Comment: note: as of beta 4 - silverlight does not include BooleanToVisibility - so you'll need to implement it yourself anyway

Comment: Added a user voice suggestion to get invert supported http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/11083446-booleantovisibilityconverter-should-allow-inverted

Comment: I can''t believe they didn't implemented some converter parameters to do such things.

Comment: Simplest solution I found was to create a property in the Model that returns negative value of the original.  

        public bool ShowMyControl
        {
            get { return !theValue; }
        }
  
  In WPF
  
   Visibility="{Binding  MyModel.ShowMyControl, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Implement your own implementation of IValueConverter.  A sample implementation is at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

In your Convert method, have it return the values you'd like instead of the defaults.

Answer (score 280):

Instead of inverting, you can achieve the same goal by using a generic `IValueConverter` implementation that can convert a Boolean value to *configurable* target values for true and false. Below is one such implementation:

```
public class BooleanConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public BooleanConverter(T trueValue, T falseValue)
    {
        True = trueValue;
        False = falseValue;
    }

    public T True { get; set; }
    public T False { get; set; }

    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is bool && ((bool) value) ? True : False;
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is T && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T) value, True);
    }
}
```

Next, subclass it where `T` is `Visibility`:

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : BooleanConverter<Visibility>
{
    public BooleanToVisibilityConverter() : 
        base(Visibility.Visible, Visibility.Collapsed) {}
}
```

Finally, this is how you could use `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` above in XAML and configure it to, for example, use `Collapsed` for true and `Visible` for false:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <app:BooleanToVisibilityConverter 
        x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" 
        True="Collapsed" 
        False="Visible" />
</Application.Resources>
```

This inversion is useful when you want to bind to a Boolean property named `IsHidden` as opposed `IsVisible`.

Comment: I might be missing something, but don't you just need a negated property ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter/11800656#11800656

Comment: @OscarRyz: With more complex UIs, that starts to add a lot of really annoying clutter to the view models, not to mention another property you theoretically have to unit test in order to maintain code coverage. View models shouldn't have to get *that* close to the implementation details of the view, otherwise you might as well just have `Visibility` properties in your view model.

Comment: This is so simple, but significantly helpful. Thank you @AtifAziz.

Comment: fyi: I posted the same solution in 2008: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2154f63-ccb5-4d6d-8c01-81f9da9ab347/invert-booleantovisibilityconverter?forum=wpf

Answer (score 54):

Write your own is the best solution for now. Here is an example of a Converter that can do both way Normal and Inverted. If you have any problems with this just ask.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    enum Parameters
    {
        Normal, Inverted
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValue = (bool)value;
        var direction = (Parameters)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parameters), (string)parameter);

        if(direction == Parameters.Inverted)
            return !boolValue? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

        return boolValue? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Converters:InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="_Converter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Visibility="{Binding IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource _Converter}, ConverterParameter=Inverted}">Start</Button>
```

Comment: Just wonding one thing.  The xaml code "Binding IsRunning", where is the sourcode or the value for the object "IsRunning"?

Comment: IsRunning is a property on my viewmodel. The context of this code is long but the short of it is that I needed to have somethings hidden when I was running some calculation and other things not hidden. I created this converter to make it so I would not have to have multiple properties on my viewmodel.

Comment: You can make it a drop-in replacement for the normal `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` by checking the parameter for null: `Parameter direction = Parameter.Normal;
if (parameter != null) direction = (Parameter)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parameter), (string)parameter);`

Answer (score 48):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var flag = false;
        if (value is bool)
        {
            flag = (bool)value;
        }
        else if (value is bool?)
        {
            var nullable = (bool?)value;
            flag = nullable.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            if (bool.Parse((string)parameter))
            {
                flag = !flag;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var back = ((value is Visibility) && (((Visibility)value) == Visibility.Visible));
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            if ((bool)parameter)
            {
                back = !back;
            }
        }
        return back;
    }
}
```

and then pass a true or false as the ConverterParameter

```
       <Grid.Visibility>
                <Binding Path="IsYesNoButtonSetVisible" Converter="{StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="true"/>
        </Grid.Visibility>
```

Comment: At the `else if (value is bool?)` part, ReSharper tells me "Expression is always false". Also, the `if (flag)` part can be rewritten more concisely as `return flag ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;`.

Comment: I might be missing something, but don't you just need a negated property ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter/11800656#11800656

Comment: `var nullable = (bool?)value; flag = nullable.GetValueOrDefault();` can be made much shorter and simple: `flag = (bool?)value ?? false;`

Answer (score 22):

One more way to Bind ViewModel Boolean Value (IsButtonVisible) with xaml Control Visibility Property.
No coding, No converting, just styling.

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type Button} x:Key="HideShow">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButtonVisible}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource HideShow}">Hello</Button>
```

Answer (score 20):

There's also the [WPF Converters](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfconverters) project on Codeplex. In their documentation they say you can use their [MapConverter](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfconverters/Wiki/View.aspx?title=User%20Documentation&referringTitle=Home#MapConverter) to convert from Visibility enumeration to bool

```
<Label>
    <Label.Visible>
        <Binding Path="IsVisible">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <con:MapConverter>
                    <con:Mapping From="True" To="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    <con:Mapping From="False" To="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                </con:MapConverter>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Label.Visible>
</Label>
```

Comment: WPF Converters now includes a BooleanToVisibilityConverter that can be reversed.

Answer (score 20):

Or the real lazy mans way, just make use of what is there already and flip it:

```
public class InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private BooleanToVisibilityConverter _converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = _converter.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture) as Visibility?;
        return result == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = _converter.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture) as bool?;
        return result == true ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't like writing custom converter, you could use data triggers to solve this:

```xaml
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourBinaryOption}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourBinaryOption}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just did a post on this.  I used a similar idea as Michael Hohlios did. Only, I used Properties instead of using the "object parameter".

[Binding Visibility to a bool value in WPF](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/)

Using Properties makes it more readable, in my opinion.

```
<local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" Collapse="True" Reverse="True" />
```

Comment: Just a follow-up on my own comment.  If you use Properties, you have to create a separate object if you want to create to converters, one that is Reverse and one not.  If you use parameters, you can use one object for multiple items, but it can be confusing if you don't pay attention.  So there are pros and cons to both.

Comment: I found this very helpful in realizing Boolean to Colors converters. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here's one I wrote and use a lot. It uses a boolean converter parameter that indicates whether or not to invert the value and then uses XOR to perform the negation:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(System.Windows.Visibility))]
public class BooleanVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    System.Windows.Visibility _visibilityWhenFalse = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="System.Windows.Visibility"/> value to use when the value is false. Defaults to collapsed.
    /// </summary>
    public System.Windows.Visibility VisibilityWhenFalse
    {
        get { return _visibilityWhenFalse; }
        set { _visibilityWhenFalse = value; }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool negateValue;
        Boolean.TryParse(parameter as string, out negateValue);

        bool val = negateValue ^ System.Convert.ToBoolean(value); //Negate the value when negateValue is true using XOR
        return val ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : _visibilityWhenFalse;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool negateValue;
        Boolean.TryParse(parameter as string, out negateValue);

        if ((System.Windows.Visibility)value == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            return true ^ negateValue;
        else
            return false ^ negateValue;
    }
}
```

Here's an XOR truth table for reference:

```
        XOR
        x  y  XOR
        ---------
        0  0  0
        0  1  1
        1  0  1
        1  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing your own code / reinventing, consider using [CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding):

```
    // Automatic two way convertion of bool expression to Visibility and 
    // back if target property has such type: description
    
    <Button Visibility="{c:Binding !IsChecked}" /> 
    <Button Visibility="{c:Binding IsChecked, FalseToVisibility=Hidden}" />
```

CalcBinding is also quite useful for numerous other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a more general answer, but could not find it. I wrote a converter that might help others.

It is based on the fact that we need to distinguish six different cases:

- True  2  Visible,   False 2 Hidden
- True  2  Visible,   False 2 Collapsed
- True  2  Hidden,    False 2 Visible
- True  2  Collapsed, False 2 Visible
- True  2  Hidden,    False 2 Collapsed
- True  2  Collapsed, False 2 Hidden

Here is my implementation for the first 4 cases:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    enum Types
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// True to Visible, False to Collapsed
        /// </summary>
        t2v_f2c,
        /// <summary>
        /// True to Visible, False to Hidden
        /// </summary>
        t2v_f2h,
        /// <summary>
        /// True to Collapsed, False to Visible
        /// </summary>
        t2c_f2v,
        /// <summary>
        /// True to Hidden, False to Visible
        /// </summary>
        t2h_f2v,
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = (bool)value;
        string p = (string)parameter;
        var type = (Types)Enum.Parse(typeof(Types), (string)parameter);
        switch (type)
        {
            case Types.t2v_f2c:
                return b ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; 
            case Types.t2v_f2h:
                return b ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden; 
            case Types.t2c_f2v:
                return b ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; 
            case Types.t2h_f2v:
                return b ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible; 
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = (Visibility)value;
        string p = (string)parameter;
        var type = (Types)Enum.Parse(typeof(Types), (string)parameter);
        switch (type)
        {
            case Types.t2v_f2c:
                if (v == Visibility.Visible)
                    return true;
                else if (v == Visibility.Collapsed)
                    return false;
                break;
            case Types.t2v_f2h:
                if (v == Visibility.Visible)
                    return true;
                else if (v == Visibility.Hidden)
                    return false;
                break;
            case Types.t2c_f2v:
                if (v == Visibility.Visible)
                    return false;
                else if (v == Visibility.Collapsed)
                    return true;
                break;
            case Types.t2h_f2v:
                if (v == Visibility.Visible)
                    return false;
                else if (v == Visibility.Hidden)
                    return true;
                break;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

example:

```
Visibility="{Binding HasItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='t2v_f2c'}"
```

I think the parameters are easy to remember.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **QuickConverter**.

With QuickConverter you can write the converter logic inline with your BindingExpression

Here is an inverted BooleanToVisibility converter:

```
Visibility="{qc:Binding '!$P ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed', P={Binding Example}}"
```

You can add QuickConverter via NuGet.
Have a look at the documentation for setup.
Link: https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Write your own convert.

```
public class ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
       // your converter code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one way version which can be used like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsHidden, Converter={x:Static Ui:Converters.BooleanToVisibility}, ConverterParameter=true}
```

can be implemented like this:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var invert = false;

    if (parameter != null)
    {
      invert = Boolean.Parse(parameter.ToString());
    }

    var booleanValue = (bool) value;

    return ((booleanValue && !invert) || (!booleanValue && invert)) 
      ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to everything (bool,string,enum,etc):

```
public class EverythingConverterValue
{
    public object ConditionValue { get; set; }
    public object ResultValue { get; set; }
}

public class EverythingConverterList : List<EverythingConverterValue>
{

}

public class EverythingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public EverythingConverterList Conditions { get; set; } = new EverythingConverterList();

    public object NullResultValue { get; set; }
    public object NullBackValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Conditions.Where(x => x.ConditionValue.Equals(value)).Select(x => x.ResultValue).FirstOrDefault() ?? NullResultValue;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Conditions.Where(x => x.ResultValue.Equals(value)).Select(x => x.ConditionValue).FirstOrDefault() ?? NullBackValue;
    }
}
```

XAML Examples:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MvvmGo.Converters;assembly=MvvmGo.WindowsWPF"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<conv:EverythingConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter">
    <conv:EverythingConverter.Conditions>
        <conv:EverythingConverterValue ResultValue="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}">
            <conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
            </conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
        </conv:EverythingConverterValue>
        <conv:EverythingConverterValue ResultValue="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}">
            <conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
        </conv:EverythingConverterValue>
    </conv:EverythingConverter.Conditions>

</conv:EverythingConverter>

<conv:EverythingConverter x:Key="InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter">
    <conv:EverythingConverter.Conditions>
        <conv:EverythingConverterValue ResultValue="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}">
            <conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
        </conv:EverythingConverterValue>
        <conv:EverythingConverterValue ResultValue="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}">
            <conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
            </conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
        </conv:EverythingConverterValue>
    </conv:EverythingConverter.Conditions>
</conv:EverythingConverter>

<conv:EverythingConverter x:Key="MarriedConverter" NullResultValue="Single">
    <conv:EverythingConverter.Conditions>
        <conv:EverythingConverterValue ResultValue="Married">
            <conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
            </conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
        </conv:EverythingConverterValue>
        <conv:EverythingConverterValue ResultValue="Single">
            <conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </conv:EverythingConverterValue.ConditionValue>
        </conv:EverythingConverterValue>
    </conv:EverythingConverter.Conditions>
    <conv:EverythingConverter.NullBackValue>
        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
    </conv:EverythingConverter.NullBackValue>
</conv:EverythingConverter>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Zamir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1335259/zamir) noted in the OP comment, by far the simplest way to do this if you are binding to a view model is to create another property to bind to that inverts the boolean value like so;

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _showThing = false;

    public bool ShowThing 
    { 
        get => _showThing;
        protected set
        {
            // flag that THiS property has changed
            _showThing = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

            // don't forget to notify the inverse has changed too
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(HideThing));
        }
    }

    public bool HideThing => !ShowThing;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This *is* conditional on binding to an underlying model however.

**Note:** If your model is bound, don't forget to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the inverted property when the source property changes.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is dated, but, you don't need to re-implement anything.

What I did was to negate the value on the property like this:

```
<!-- XAML code -->
<StackPanel Name="x"  Visibility="{Binding    Path=Specials, ElementName=MyWindow, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"></StackPanel>    
<StackPanel Name="y"  Visibility="{Binding Path=NotSpecials, ElementName=MyWindow, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"></StackPanel>
```

....

```
//Code behind
public bool Specials
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(SpecialsProperty); }
    set
    {
        NotSpecials= !value; 
        SetValue(SpecialsProperty, value);
    }
}

public bool NotSpecials
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(NotSpecialsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NotSpecialsProperty, value); }
}
```

And it works just fine!

Am I missing something?

Comment: You think this is an easier solution, and for a single property this might even be the case (it's not reusable for multiple properties, you have to implement it for every one). I feel this is the wrong place for the implementation though, as it has nothing to do with the viewmodel/codeBehind and everything with the view.