# WPF Binding: !value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have button:

```
<Button Content="Stop loading" />
```

In ViewModel i have property IsLoaded. I don't want to write property IsNotLoaded but i want to use IsLoaded in binding and disable button when IsLoaded = true.

How implement something like this:

```
<Button Content="Stop loading" IsEnabled="{Binding !IsLoaded}" />
```

P.S. if it more difficult than writing of additional property, i will use IsNotLoaded property.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039636/how-to-bind-inverse-boolean-properties-in-wpf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the converter answers are all valid, you may want to look at an alternative methodology: Commanding.

In WPF (and somewhat in Silverlight), you can bind an ICommand to that button.  So, if you created, on your ViewModel, a property called CancelLoadingCommand that implemented ICommand, you'd bind the button as follows:

```
<Button Content="Stop Loading" Command="{Binding CancelLoadingCommand}" />
```

The implementation of the CancelLoadingCommand in your ViewModel would look something like:

```
    public ICommand CancelLoadingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cancelLoadingCommand== null)
            {
                this._cancelLoadingCommand= new RelayCommand(
                    delegate
                    {
                        // Cancel the loading process.
                    },
                    delegate
                    {
                        return !this.IsLoaded;
                    }
                );
            }

            return _cancelLoadingCommand;
        }
    }
```

Note, I'm using a RelayCommand here (which is part of the PRISM or MVVM-Light frameworks). I'd suggest looking into one of those as well.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 27):

The standard means of doing this is to make an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that will invert your boolean values.  While creating this class is more difficult than adding a new property, it's completely reusable - so later, you can reuse this in other bindings (without polluting your ViewModel with lots of !Property properties).

This class would look something like:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
public class InvertBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool booleanValue = (bool)value;
        return !booleanValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool booleanValue = (bool)value;
        return !booleanValue;
    }
}
```

Then, you would add it to your resources:

```
<src:InvertBoolConverter x:Key="invertBoolConverter"/>
```

Once you have this, you would use it like:

```
<Button Content="Stop loading" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoaded, Converter={StaticResource invertBoolConverter}}" 
/>
```

Comment: You'd think Microsoft would provide one of these.  They already provide BooleanToVisibilityConverter.  Why not a handful of other helpful ones?

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to use a converter to invert the boolean value.  Something like

```
public class InvertedBoolenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

Then add the converter to a resource somewhere and use it in the binding:

```
<YourUserControl.Resources>
   <c:InvertedBoolenConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolenConverter" />
</YourUserControl.Resources>

<Button Content="Stop loading" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoaded,Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolenConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use a converter.  Here is one that will do the trick for you.

```
  public class booleaninverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return !(bool)value;
    }
  }
```

To use it, write your xaml like so

```
<Button Content="Stop loading" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoaded, Converter={StaticResource booleaninverter}" />
```

You can make the static resource in your App.xaml, or other window / control resources section.  Of course you have to make the 'local' namespace declarations and what-not, but this is most of the work done for you.

```
<local:booleaninverter x:key="booleaninverter"/>
```