# formulas in WPF bindings

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I have a combobox, and I want it to be enabled when checkbox is not checked. How do I write it? I tried following, but it seems that WPF doesn't recognise this syntax:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled={Binding Path=!CheckBoxIsChecked, Mode=OneWay}/>
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding Path=CheckBoxIsChecked}/>
```

Comment: I believe more generic approach would be introducing InverseBooleanConverter ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1039681/485076)) and use it where you need instead of copy-paste trigger across multiple Views

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind inverse boolean properties in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039636/how-to-bind-inverse-boolean-properties-in-wpf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A trigger should work just as well for this:

```
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxIsChecked}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckBoxIsChecked}" Value="False" >
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckBoxIsChecked}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Wouldn't prefer this solution as sll already mentioned. It's a lot more code and less maintainable over multiple editors in multiple places in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a converter, i.e. a class that implements the [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) interface. The converter will then be assigned to the Converter property of your binding:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CheckBoxIsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: It is easier to write a property CheckBoxIsNotChecked { get { return !CheckBoxIsChecked; } }

Comment: Yes, but what if you bind to an object that you don't write yourself, i.e. where you have no control over the set of properties?

Answer (score 1):

You should use so-called converters to do these kind of things.

```
{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter=BoolToVisibilityConverter}
```

BoolToVisibilityConverter is a standard WPF converter. You can also easily write a OppositeBoolToVisibilityConverter. Many examples around on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use convertor to achieve this.

```
public class BooleanNegationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ConvertValue(value);
    }
    private bool ConvertValue(object value)
    {
        bool boolValue;
        if(!Boolean.TryParse(value.ToString(), out boolValue))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value that was being converted was not a Boolean", "value");
        }
        return !boolValue;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ConvertValue(value);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CheckBoxIsChecked, 
                              Mode=OneWay, 
                              Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverterKey}}"/>
```

Remember you have to declare this static resource in xaml resources. Like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanNegationConverter x:Key="BooleanNegationConverterKey" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```