# The attachable property 'IsEnabled' was not found in type 'TextBox'

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, attached-properties, isenabled

From my understanding of attached properties, I believe that I can set a property value that will apply to all of the children of a container that match the type.  For instance, if I have a number of TextBoxes in a StackPanel, then I can disable them all by setting the TextBox.IsEnabled property to false in the StackPanel's declaration:

```
<StackPanel TextBox.IsEnabled="False" Orientation="Horizontal">
...
</StackPanel>
```

I tried this in Visual Studio, and the Xaml designer greyed-out the TextBoxes in the StackPanel exactly as expected, but when I tried to compile, I ran into the error:

> The attachable property 'IsEnabled' was not found in type 'TextBox'

Have I misunderstood attached properties?  Do they only go from the ancestor to the child?  If so, is there a way to do what I am trying, ie, to set all child `TextBox`es `IsEnabled` property to false?

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051226/how-to-set-isreadonly-isenabled-on-entire-container-like-panel-or-groupbox-usi try to look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, attached properties allow to set a property value on the parent and the children inherit that value. On the other hand `TextBox.IsEnabled` is not an attached property and so you cannot do what you want.

Perhaps it is possible to get what you want with some custom panels and/or custom attached properties programming.

However you could also get the same result using a `Style` where you can also bind the IsEnabled property to your custom logic if you need.

```
<StackPanel Width="200" Height="50" >
     <StackPanel.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="TextBox">
             <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
         </Style>
     </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox Text="one" />
        <TextBox Text="two" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'm only dealing with a few textboxes and they are static (ie always RO), so I was just looking to find a shortcut to save me typing IsEnabled="False" a handful of times.  I've obviously not quite got Attached properties from my readings, I thought they would bubble up as well as tunnel down.  Oh well.  I've now decided to just set IsEnabled in each of the TextBoxes.  thanks for looking in. You've said I can't do it, so I'm calling it the answer.  cheers.

Comment: Tunneling and bubbling concepts are related to routed events. In case of (attached) properties one speaks about value inheritance.