# Disable text box when Check box is Unchecked during run time in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a CheckBox and a TextBox. During the runtime,
if the CheckBox is Checked then the TextBox is enabled.

I did it using following code

```
private void checkTime_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkTime.IsChecked == true)
    {
        txtTime_SR.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

What I need to do is, to disable the TextBox when the CheckBox is Unchecked during runtime.

Any idea of doing this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading your post and comments, I'll guess you are doing WPF or silverlight.
Then, in that case, you may do it all in XAML :

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkTime" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtTime_SR" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkTime, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Then, you need to create the converter. This can be done by reading post here : [How to bind inverse boolean properties in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039636/how-to-bind-inverse-boolean-properties-in-wpf)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

If I understand, you want the textbox to be enabled when the checkbox is checked, and for it to be disabled when the checkbox is unchecked?

```
private void checkTime_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtTime_SR.Enabled = checkTime.Checked;
}
```

Are you using the standard .NET `TextBox` and `CheckBox` controls?

EDIT:  Ok, so it is WPF.  Do this:

```
private void checkTime_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtTime_SR.IsEnabled = checkTime.IsChecked;
}
```

Comment: I'm not well experienced in .Net. For the text box there is no "Enabled" method. There is only "IsEnabled" method. :(

Comment: Then try with `IsEnabled` and `IsChecked` - it should work if they aren't read-only properties.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler

```html
<CheckBox Content="Include the following..." IsChecked="{Binding IncludeMyItems}" Name="checkBox_includeMyItems" />
<TextBox Name="myItems" Text="{Binding MyItems}" Height="23" Width="165" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox_includeMyItems}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checkTime_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 txtTime_SR.Enabled = checkTime.Checked;
}
```

**OR**

```
private void checkTime_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtTime_SR.IsEnabled = checkTime.IsChecked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, however this should work. Use the Checked/Unchecked events.

```
   private void checkbox_otherflag_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textbox_otherflagtext.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void checkbox_otherflag_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textbox_otherflagtext.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```