# How can I bind a control to another control's opposite value?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, maui

I have an entry control and I'm looking to set it up as a password. I also have a check box control that I want to setup  as a show-password checkbox. My XAML code looks like this:

```xml
<Entry Placeholder="Enter Password Viewing Password"
       Grid.Row="3"
       TextColor="White"
       x:Name="vwPasswrd"
       BindingContext="{x:Reference chkVwPasswdShow}"
       IsPassword="{Binding IsChecked}"
       Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

<HorizontalStackLayout
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalOptions="Center">

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkVwPasswdShow"
              VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            
    <Label Text="Show Password"
           FontSize="Micro"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           TextColor="White"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

However, the way this code is, the checkbox is unchecked and when the user starts entering data into the entry control, actual text is displayed. And when the checkbox is clicked, then the text is displayed as password dots.

I would like it done in reverse:

1. When the checkbox is unchecked, I would like the text displayed as password dots.
2. When the checkbox is checked, I would like the text displayed as plain text.

I seems like I have to bind it in a reverse way. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind inverse boolean properties in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039636/how-to-bind-inverse-boolean-properties-in-wpf)

Comment: Also may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385812/negating-a-boolean-property-when-data-binding-and-applying-converter

Comment: @Serg This seems to be MAUI, not WPF (notice the *HorizontalStackLayout*).

Comment: The `ValueConverter`s concept exists in both WPF and MAUI (and in other UI frameworks as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [InvertedBoolConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/inverted-bool-converter) from the [MAUI Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) for this:

```xml
<!-- Add converter here -->
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <toolkit:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid>

    <!-- use it here: -->
    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Password Viewing Password"
           Grid.Row="3"
           TextColor="White"
           x:Name="vwPasswrd"
           BindingContext="{x:Reference chkVwPasswdShow}"
           IsPassword="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}"
           Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

    <!-- ... -->

</Grid>
```