# Creating a WPF editor for XML file based on schema

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, xsd

Here's the scenario. We use a large XML configuration file for one of our server products. This file is fairly well layed out and is validated against an XSD file.

It's time now though to build a configuration GUI for maintaining this file and I would like to dive into WPF to do it. I could lay out a seperate form for each config section, refactoring and redistributing every time we add an option to the config file but I'm hoping there is a more clever way of doing this.

Since I already have a strongly typed xml/xsd combination I am hoping there is an elegant method for building a UI to edit this easily enough. I know I could write an xml->xaml transformation but was hoping there is something out there to do the heavy lifting for me already?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How I'd do this:

I'd start by building a simple view-model class that wraps around an `XmlElement` and exposes it as a configuration option.  This class could be *extremely* simple, e.g.:

```
public class OptionView
{
   private XmlElement XmlElement;
   public OptionView(XmlElement xmlElement)
   {
      XmlElement = xmlElement;
   }
   public string Name { get { return XmlElement.Name; } }
   public string Value 
   { 
      get { return XmlElement.InnerText; } 
      set { XmlElement.InnerText = value; }
   }
}
```

Now I can populate a collection of `ElementView` objects from an `XmlDocument`, add that collection to the window's `ResourceDictionary`, and format the objects with a simple `DataTemplate`, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OptionViewTemplate" DataType={x:Type local:OptionView}>
   <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Name"/>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Value"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
...
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
    ItemsSource="{DynamicResource OptionCollection}"/>
```

(Note:  Later, you can get fancy, and define subclasses of `OptionView` based on, for instance, the data type of the underlying `XmlElement`.  Then you can define `DataTemplate`s for each subclass, and as long as each presents the item in a two-column grid using that `SharedSizeGroup`, the second column can contain a date picker, or radio buttons, or whatever is appropriate to the subclass, and it'll all get neatly laid out at runtime.)

Once I got that working, which wouldn't take long, I'd start extending the `OptionView` class.  For instance, if your schema is storing a human-readable label for an element in an `xs:annotation` element (and if it isn't, why not?), I'd make the `Name` property extract that out of the `XmlElement`'s `SchemaInfo` property, instead of exposing the underlying element name.

Obviously I'd want to add validation, so I'd add a validation method that examined the `XmlElement`'s `SchemaInfo` property and interpreted it.  (Assuming that the elements you're validating are simple content, that shouldn't be hard.)  There's a million tutorials on how to implement validation in WPF applications, so I won't go into too much detail here.

If there are tons of configuration options and you have some intelligent way of grouping them into categories, I'd build a higher level class that exposed (at least) two properties - a string `CategoryName` property and an `OptionsViews` collection - populate it from the XML document, and add it to the window's `ResourceDictionary`.  Within the window, I'd bind it to a `TabControl`, e.g.:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{DynamicResource OptionCategories}">
   <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type CategoryView}">
         <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"/>
         <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=OptionsViews}"/>
         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OptionViewTemplate}"/>
      </Style>
   </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Or to some item control whose item container template creates an `Expander`.  Or something.  (All code guaranteed untested!  Most of it was copied out of working projects, though.)

If you haven't done anything with WPF before, this is a pretty good project to start on.  It'll expose you to the fundamentals of data binding and items controls and validation, and the end result will be something that's useful and probably looks pretty good.

And you'll notice that while the markup involved in creating the templates is pretty verbose, there are only two templates.  The only code in the application (so far) is the code that exposes the `XmlElement`s to the UI.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, we created one for your requirement. this tool fully created by keeping WPF in mind.

http://wpfxmleditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you plan on doing a release for your editor? It's currently only source and there's no indication of the state of the code (i.e., is it mostly complete? alpha, beta, stable?)

Comment: i am sorry for late reply, i dont have any plan for release, you can download and build it.

Comment: @Gomes Broken link

Comment: @cederlof , https://github.com/GomesNayagam/wpfxmleditor seems to be a copy of sources from codeplex, the rest can be found in [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223232752/http://wpfxmleditor.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not WPF but very enlightening - [A Dynamically Generated XML Data Editor by Marc Clifton](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3645/A-Dynamically-Generated-XML-Data-Editor)

an article with source code for windows forms about creating a GUI for editing an XML based on XSD.

Have been searching long for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

To present simple xml configs (if custom editors for values are not required) one can directly bind XElement to a view using HierarchicalDataTemplate.

xaml:

```
<TreeView Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Xml.Elements}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Name"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Value"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                <!--Show TextBox only for leaf elements-->
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                         Text="{Binding Value}" 
                         Visibility="{Binding HasElements,
                            Converter={StaticResource reverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

view model:

```
class ConfigViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public XElement Xml { get; private set;}

    //example of persistence infrastructure
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public void Load(string fileName)
    {
        Xml = XElement.Load(fileName);
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Xml"));
    }
    public void Save(string fileName)
    {
        Xml.Save(fileName);
    }
}
```

[There are some good examples for reversed bool to visibility converter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter)