# WPF - Bind UserControl visibility to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, controltemplate

I have a ListView bound to ObservableCollection. Data are loaded from the internet and then added to collection. The download takes few seconds and I want to indicate user that the data is loading.

I created an UserControl that indicates activity. I placed it inside of ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Grid>
        <local:ActivityIndicatorControl 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="Auto" 
            Margin="0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I would like to bind Visibility of `ActivityIndicatorControl` to a property, let's say `bool IsLoading` and set it to Visible/Collapsed correspondingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would recommend using a [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to accept your boolean, and return a member of Visibility enumeration.

Here is a good example of one: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/10/27/binding-converters---visibilityconverter.aspx

The XAML would look like this:

First you define a resource for the converter (put this in a resource dictionary):

```
<local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="myBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
```

And then change your template like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource myBoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <local:ActivityIndicatorControl 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="Auto" 
            Margin="0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Also, does the UserControl inherit DataContext from Grid? Would it be possible to create the binding on the UserControl itself?

Comment: Yes, the UserControl would have the same DataContext as the Grid.  Because of this, you could put the visibility binding on the UserControl with no problem.

Comment: A small note: change BooleanToVisibiltyConverter to BooleanToVisibilityConverter (add missing "i") and it looks like this: <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="myBoolToVisibilityConverter" />

Answer (score 2):

## Use .NET's built in Converter

.NET 3 has a built in [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

(Note: May not be available on all platforms, ex: mobile)

First add it to your Resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2vis"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then use it on an element

```
<Label Visibility="{Binding IsSomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource bool2vis}}" />
```

## Inverting

[How do I invert BooleanToVisibilityConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter)

If you want to invert the converter (ex: hide the element when your property is true), this answer has a custom implementation of `IValueConverter` that supports that via XAML

```
<Application.Resources>
    <app:BooleanToVisibilityConverter 
        x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" 
        True="Collapsed" 
        False="Visible" />
</Application.Resources>
```