# MVVM Light UniversalConverter bool to Visibility

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying to make a pair of `TextBlock`s toggle (one `Visible`, the other `Collapsed` and vice-versa) on a bound boolean.

I could use `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` for one but can't do a ! for the other so I'm trying to use MVVM Light's `UniversalConverter` which takes a lambda in the `ConverterParameter`.

Trouble is, I can't find any examples of the use and my attempts fail.

I've declared it in the XAML resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ex:UniversalConverter x:Key="UniversalConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and then added this to the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowA, Converter={StaticResource universalConverter}, ConverterParameter='b=>b?Visible:Collapsed'}">A</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowA, Converter={StaticResource universalConverter}, ConverterParameter='b=>b?Collapsed:Visible'}">B</TextBlock>
```

This throws an exception in the XAML design windows: `Unknown identifier 'Visible'`.

I've also tried `b=>b?Visibility.Visible:Visibility.Collapsed` which is an example in the UniversalConverter's `Convert` method comment; that throws `Unknown identifier 'Visibility'`.

How do I add the references needed to the `UniversalConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I never used the `UniversalConverter` class from the excellent MVVM Light toolkit framework, so I can't answer your specific question "how to make it work".

But in order to solve your **actual** issue, you can create your own `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` that allows **inverting the mapping between true/false and Visible/Collapsed**. See [How do I invert BooleanToVisibilityConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter) for examples.

Personally I really would avoid to use the `UniversalConverter` for many reasons:

- undocumented as you now know
- forces to write programming logic in the XAML, which is not the primary goal of the XAML...
- ... forces to write C# line of code that cannot be debugged (at least for VS2010 + .Net 4), which means this converter is a wrong approach IMHO

Comment: I have to admit that I don't disagree with Ken. UniversalConverter is something I tried playing with, but I must admit that I never use it. Seriously considering deprecating it and eventually removing it from MVVM Light.

Comment: Well if Laurent "doesn't disagree" then ken must be right. I guess I wanted to use the UniversalConverter because it seemed like a quick win (_marginally_ quicker than writing my own specific converter)...

Answer (score 0):

It seems `UniversalConverter` has been removed since year 2013

http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2013/01/mvvm-light-v4-1-26-change-log/

> BL0023.004, Remove UniversalConverter