# Is there an IValueConverter that does if-then

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**What I am trying to do:**

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
    <!--The next line is pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve-->
    <RowDefintion Height="if(EditEnabled) { 10* } else { 0 }" />
    ...
  </Grid.RowDefinition>
  ...
  <DockPanel Visibility="{Binding EditEnabled, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ...>
  ...
```

I am trying to change the visibility of the DockPanel depending on whether editing is enabled, while keeping he ability to resize and have fixed heights and relative heights.

**The question:**

Is there an `IValueConverter` (`System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter`) that can take a boolean, and two numbers and choose one of the `GridLength`s based on the boolean? From just inspecting the interface of `IValueConverter` it doesn't look like this is quite the right type to use.

Or is there a better way to inject the `GridLength` that I want?

**What I have tried:**

- Looking through the inheritors of `IValueConverter` - nothing obvious to me
- Moving the `Height="10*"` inside the `DockPanel` tag and changing the `RowDefinition` to be `Auto` - this created an conversion exception
- Searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf%20xaml%20if%20then)

Comment: You can use `IMultiValueConverter`. There is no built in one. You have to create your own. It's really simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `IValueConverter` that does if-then.
(and to be more specific: you can not do if-then logic with the XAML)
But you can do the if-then logic in the C# code.
here is the solution

```
public class HeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool enableEdit = (bool)value;
        double param = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

        if (enableEdit)
            return new GridLength(param, GridUnitType.Star);
        else
            return new GridLength(0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and the window like this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HeightConverter x:Key="heightConverter"/>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="param">10</sys:Int32>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=EditEnabled, Converter={StaticResource heightConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource param}}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

please consider also define the required namespace that you will use, like the following

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:[your namespace]"
```

**Update** the same result could be achieved by using [IMutliValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class HeightMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool enableEdit = (bool)values[0];
        double param = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);

        if (enableEdit)
            return new GridLength(param, GridUnitType.Star);
        else
            return new GridLength(0);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and the window like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HeightMultiConverter x:Key="heightMutliConverter"/>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="param">10</sys:Int32>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition >
            <RowDefinition.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource heightMutliConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="EditEnabled"/>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource param}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RowDefinition.Height>
        </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

NOTE: just do not forget, you have to take care of the `Source` by setting the `DataContext` property.

Comment: That looks like what I want except that the `10` is hard coded - not passed in. I'm guessing that the `Convert` method only takes a `bool` or a number?

Comment: if you want to pass in the value of 10 there is a way to do that , I will updated my answer for you to use parameter

Comment: @Jonny `HeightConverter` can have properties and you can set their values the same way you would for any other type. You can put the `10` in such a property, and read that property in your `Convert` implementation.

Comment: Just add two properties in the converter Class and set them accordingly in the xaml: <Window.Resources>
    <conv:HeightConverter x:Key="heightConverter" TrueLength="100" FalseLength="0"/>
  </Window.Resources> Instead of just returning the two fixed values 10 and 0, just use those added properties.

Comment: @Jonny I updated my answer and I tested it. it is working and you can pass the 10 as parameter to the converter without hard coded it

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in converter you may be able to use: [`AlternationConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.alternationconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). You specify a list of values (of arbitrary type), bind to an integer, and the converter looks up the integer in the list of values (modulo the value count).

If you specify two values for this `AlternationConverter`, and you're able to provide your `EditEnabled` property as an integer `0` or `1`, then you can map that `0` and `1` to any value you want.

If you feel it doesn't make sense to convert your `bool` to an integer first (something I can sympathise with), you could still use `AlternationConverter` as inspiration for a custom converter that doesn't require the model value to be of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BooleanConverter<T>` base class as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182660/469708

```
public class BooleanConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public BooleanConverter(T trueValue, T falseValue)
    {
        True = trueValue;
        False = falseValue;
    }

    public T True { get; set; }
    public T False { get; set; }

    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is bool && ((bool) value) ? True : False;
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is T && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T) value, True);
    }
}
```

Then write

```
public class BooleanToGridLengthConverter : BooleanConverter<System.Windows.GridLength>
{
   public BooleanToGridLengthConverter() : base(
     new System.Windows.GridLength(1, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star),
     new System.Windows.GridLength(0))
   {
   }
}
```

The values for true and false can be set directly, no need for a MultiValueConverter (as long as only the boolean parameter needs to be bindable).

```
<convert:BooleanToGridLengthConverter x:Key="Converter" True="10*" False="0" />
```

Alternatively, you can derive the converter from MarkupExtension and directly use it like this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding EditEnabled, Converter={convert:BooleanToGridLengthConverter True=10*, False=0}" />
```