# Invert the output of the boolean visibility converter?

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I have an element whose visibility should be bound to a checkbox. I can use BindingPath=IsChecked and Converter={StaticResource convVisibility} to make it visible. However, I want to make it hidden and there is no BindingPath=IsUnchecked. Can I invert the value of the boolean to visibility converter? Thanks for help.

This is in the window xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="convVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invert BooleanToVisibilityConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter)

Comment: I think magic will happen anyway if you just bind to IsChecked property.

Comment: @Clemens I agree

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution of this problem:

```
public class BoolVisibilityCollapsedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool param = true;

            if (parameter != null)
                param = System.Convert.ToBoolean(parameter);

            bool state = (bool)value;

            Visibility visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            if (state != param)
                visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            return visibility;
        }
```

If you use this converter, you will switch visibilty like True = Visible / False = Collapsed. If you want the different behavior (True = Collapsed / False = Visible) just use CommandParameter="False"